# Get Current URL in Formula Field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have a formula field that looks something like below:

```
HYPERLINK(
  "/apex/RelationshipManagement?id=" &  Id, 
  IMAGE(
    "https://unitingambition--goodwin--c.cs80.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015250000000zaQ&oid=00D25000000DfEU&lastMod=1449504973000",
    "UA Logo",
    16,
    16
  ),
  "_popup"
)
```

As you can see I'm passing in the Id of a Contact record as a paramer to the URL.

What I would like to know is how I can pass in the current URL in a formula field.

The reason we're using a formula field here as opposed to a button is that this link will need to display on a report and the Visualforce Page needs to be accessible from both reports and the records themselves.

I figured if I could somehow pass in the URL It'd be easy to redirect to that URL, but I'm not sure how and haven't had much luck in researching it. Ideally it would look something like this:

```
"/apex/RelationshipManagement?id=" &  Id  & "&retURL="  &  retUrl,
```

Any help/ideas would be appreciated!